# How to structure multiple pages with RequireJS

Tags: module, requirejs

How to structure multiple pages with RequireJS? Is, like the following sample, declaring every class in app.js is the right thing to do? Has every html file to declare the `<script data-main="src/main" src="src/require.js"></script>`?

What I want to avoid is loading all the script when a user reach the first page of a site.

**main.js defining all external dependencies:**

```
require(
    {
        baseUrl:'/src'
    },
    [
        "require",
        "order!http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js",
        "order!http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js",
        "order!http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.1.6/underscore-min.js",
        "order!http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.3.3/backbone-min.js"
    ], 
    function (require) {
        require(["app"], function (app) {
            app.start();
        });
    }
);
```

**app.js file defining every component:**

```
define([ "product/ProductSearchView",
         "product/ProductCollection"
         ], function (ProductSearchView,
                      ProductCollection) {
         return {
             start: function() {
                  var products = new ProductCollection();
                  var searchView = new ProductSearchView({ collection: products });
                  products.fetch();
                  return {};
             }
        }
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can require files within your existing module. So say when someone clicks a link you could trigger a function that does the following:

```
// If you have a require in your other module
// The other module will execute its own logic
require(["module/one"], function(One) {
    $("a").click(function() {
        require(["new/module"]);
    });
});

// If you have a define in your other module
// You will need to add the variable to the require
// so you can access its methods and properties
require(["module/one"], function(One) {
    $("a").click(function() {
        require(["new/module"], function(NewModule) {
            NewModule.doSomething();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Does the `new/module` should be named? If it's not, how to use, say, its `clean()` method?

Comment: Ah, and is `require` has to be in another `require` or can it appears in a `define` bloc?

Comment: You can name it if you want, in that case you'd want to create a define in the new/module. I'm currently using it without the name because it will just run its own logic.

Answer (score 3):

This is a complete example of how this all works; [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) and [order.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html#order) are in the same directory as the app's JS files.

```
<html> 
  <head>  
    <script data-main="js/test" src="js/require.js"></script>
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <button>Clickme</button>
  </body> 
</html>
```

test.js (in js folder)

```
require(
  {
    baseUrl:'/js'
  },
  [
    "order!//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js",
    "order!//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js"
  ], 
  function () {
    require(["app"], function (app) {
      app.start();
    });
  }
);
```

app.js (in js folder) with a on-demand load of Employee.js:

```
define([], function () {
  return {
    start: function() {
      $('button').button();
      $('button').click(function() {
        require(['Employee'], function(Employee) {
          var john = new Employee('John', 'Smith');
          console.log(john);
          john.wep();
        });
      });

      return {};
    }
  }
});
```

Employee.js (in js folder):

```
define('Employee', function () {
  return function Employee(first, last) {
    this.first = first; 
    this.last = last;
    this.wep = function() {
        console.log('wee');
    }
  };
});
```