# How to structure a complex web app with RequireJS

Tags: module, requirejs

I saw there is somes questions related to mine (like [this interesting one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184734/how-to-structure-multiple-pages-with-requirejs)), but what I wonders is how to do it correctly, and I couldn't find it via the others questions or the RequireJS documentation.

I'm working on a quite heavy web application that will run in only one html page.

Before RequireJS, I used to do a lot of JS modules with public methods and connecting them via the `on` event on the Dom READY method, like this :

```
var DataList = function () {
    this.base = arguments[0];
    this.onUpdate = function (event) { ... }
}

$(function () {
    var dataList = {}; DataList.apply(dataList, [$('#content')]);
    $('table.main', dataList.base).on ('update', dataList.onUpdate);
});
```

With RequireJS, I can easily see that I can split DataList and all others classes like this on individual files, but what about the `$(function () {});` part?

Can I still keep it this way, but instead of the DOM ready function of jQuery, I put the events on the main function() of the RequireJS, when my primary libs are loaded?

Or do I have to change the way I create JS "classes", to include a init function maybe, that will be called when I do a, for example :

```
require(['Datalist'], function(dataList) {
    dataList.init($('#content'));
});
```

What annoys me the most is that since I have only one html file, I'm afraid the `require()` will have to load a huge list of files, I'd prefer it to load just libs that, them, would load sub libs required to work.

I don't know, the way of thinking with RequireJS lost me a bit :/

How would you do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*Can I still keep it this way, but instead of the DOM ready function of jQuery, I put the events on the main function() of the RequireJS, when my primary libs are loaded?*"

If you separate the functions or 'classes' into modules then you can use the RequireJS `domReady` function:

```
require(['module1'], function(module1) {
    domReady(function(){
        // Some code here ftw
    })
});
```

The benefit here is the `domReady` function will allow downloading of the modules instantly but won't execute them until your DOM is ready to go.

*"Or do I have to change the way I create JS "classes", to include a init function maybe, that will be called when I do a, for example"*

You won't need to change the way you interact with your code this way, but you can probably improve it. In your example I would make DataList a module:

```
define(function(require) {
    var $ = require('jquery');

    var DataList = function () {
        this.base = arguments[0];
    };

    DataList.prototype.onUpdate = function() {

    };

    return DataList;
});

require(['data-list'], function(DataList) {

    var data = {};

    // Call DataList with new and you won't need to set the context with apply
    // otherwise it can be used exactly as your example
    new DataList(data);

});
```

*"What annoys me the most is that since I have only one html file, I'm afraid the require() will have to load a huge list of files, I'd prefer it to load just libs that, them, would load sub libs required to work."*

Make your code as modular as you want/can and [then use the optimiser](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) to package it into one JS file.

Comment: That's interesting! But where do I put the `$('table.main', dataList.base).on ('update', dataList.onUpdate);` code ? in the `DataList` constructor or just after the `new DataList(data)` ?

Comment: You could pass it as an argument to DataList and act upon it in the constructor so your code looks like new DataList($('element'), data);